# "Accept clipboard from viewers" not working in Tiger VNC on KDE RHEL 7.4

Tags: rhel, kde, tigervnc

When running `vncserver` and `vncconfig -display :1 &`, the clipboard works only from the server to the client, but not from the client to the server, even though `Accept clipboard from viewers` is checked.

On the client (Windows 10) "Send clipboard to server checkbox is also checked.

What are the troubleshooting steps for this issue?

Comment: KDE spawns a clipboard manager called klipper. I have had tons of issues with klipper in VNCs. Try killing the klipper process in your vnc and see if that helps.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wrote an answer that includes how to manually stop klipper from starting when you create a vncserver, glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KDE spawns a clipboard manager called klipper. I have had tons of issues with klipper in VNCs. It seems to override all copying and pasting. The process will be running as whatever user started the VNC server, so you can kill it manually from a command line in the VNC itself. If you want to manually disable klipper from starting automatically for that user you can edit (or create) the file `~/.kde/share/config/klipperrc`. Add `AutoStart=false` under the `[General]` section like so:

```
[General]
AutoStart=false
```

This way next time you start up a vncserver you will not have to deal with this problem again.